# update with increment value in mongodb without foreach

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My collection like this:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5b9ba196cd5f5af83bb0dc71"),
   "name" : "madhab",
   "age":18,
   "userId":"TAP1"
}
```

I want update `userId` where **userId** doesn't exist or null.
But my **userId** like this `"TAP"+{Something}` and it must be **unique**.

I know I can use `forEach` like below

```
var counter = 1;
db.collection.find().forEach(
  function(elem) { 
    db.myColl.update(
      { "userId" : { $exists: false, $in: [null, ""] }}, 
      {$set:{ "userId": {$concat:["TAP",counter]}  } 
      }); 
   counter++;
});
```

**but I don't want to use foreach**

Help me guys if any idea.

Comment: What version of MongoDB?

Comment: 3.6 version i am using

Comment: so ur saying the for loop is only for the counter increment?

Comment: yes, i want this counter without forloop @VipulDessai

Comment: any idea how to do with other version

Comment: what you are trying to achieve doesn't seem possible with just query operations, even the example code should be fetching all the items where _**userId**_ is null first and then looping over them setting the value of the counter

Comment: you are saying,it is not possible @VipulDessai

Comment: at least from the perspective of just using an query, correct me if I'm wrong, you are trying out auto-incrementing similar to _**$inc**_ operator or an auto _**id**_ when null is inserted in the query. isn't it?

Comment: yes i want this